git log %d directive and truncation
I'm trying to create a log format that uses truncation inspired by this SO answer but still decorates:
git log --format="tformat:%d %<($(($(tput cols)-20)),trunc)%s"

But, using git 2.43.0, %d seems to expand too late resulting in lines too long whenever the decoration is longer than 20 chars.
Is there a solution to avoid these newlines ?
Edit:
Note that after @larsks answer, I understood that I was not correctly formalizing my problem which is more like:

How do I truncate the following git log invocation to window width:

git log --format="tformat:%C(auto)%d%C(reset) %s"

I was wrongly using the %< mechanism and got a bit confused by the answers I found.
My first (new) answer to the problem was the following:
git log --format="tformat:%C(auto)%d%C(reset) %s" --color=always | grep -Eo "^(([[:cntrl:]]\[[0-9;]{,4}m)*[[:print:]]){,$(tput cols)}" | less -r

where the grep invocation comes from this SO answer.
However, this solution comes with several drawbacks that I’ll need to tackle:

getting the log is slower (it pipes everything to grep, no more paging)
it’s not natively paging but uses less (which changes a bit my user experience)

So I believe, the definite answer is this one
$ git config --global core.pager 'less -SR'

where:

-S stands for --chop-long-lines Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped (truncated) rather than wrapped.
-R to keep colors

which answers all my needs.

Indeed. Fixed. Asked the question from my phone...

It doesn't have anything to do with %d expanding "too late". You are only applying the truncate option to the %s token; it doesn't impact %d at all. You could explicitly truncate %d as well, with something like:
git log --format="tformat:%<(20,trunc)%d %<(60,trunc)%s"

This gets you output like:
 (HEAD -> main, up.. Upgrade to version 4.13.13 (#416)                     
                     Merge pull request #415 from alice/feature/newthing
 (origin/feature/o.. Configure test cluster to trust internal ca                 
                     Fix the thing
                     Fix the other thing

Or you could just pipe everything through cut:
git log --format="tformat:%d %s" | cut -c 1-$(($(tput cols)-20))


Oh, right ! So, either for every line I should get the length of my prefix (including %d) or get cut to keep my formatting options. I'll look into this.
